# Setting & clearing session flash in hapijs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I want to set up flash error message in hapijs. I referred these two questions:

[How to set Flash Messages in Hapi JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963596/how-to-set-flash-messages-in-hapi-js)
[Hapijs Custom 500 Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184744/hapijs-custom-500-error-page)

Here is the `onPreResponse`:

```
server.ext("onPreResponse", (request, reply) => {
  let response = request.response;
  if (response.variety === "view") {
    if (!response.source.context) {
      response.source.context = {};
    }
    let flashError = request["yar"].get("error");
    if (flashError) {
      response.source.context["err"] = flashError;
    }
  }
```

Then in the handler, I set using `request["yar"].set("error", err["message"]);`

But the session variable (`err`) is never cleared. I tried `request["yar".get("error", true)` as well as `request["yar"].set("error","")`. This causes the views to display the same error as the user navigates through the screens.

I also tried with `request["yar"].flash()`, which gave me the same results.

How to set flash/temporary error messages to show in the views?

Comment: How are you setting the "err" cookie? Can you show your handler function? Also what version of "hapi" and "yar"?

Answer (score 1):

yar.set() will set normal session data that is not deleted on read.You need to use the flash method both to store and to retrieve the flashes.

> flash(type, message, isOverride) - stores volatile data - data that should be deleted once read. When given no arguments, it will return all of the flash messages and delete the originals. When given only a type, it will return all of the flash messages of that type and delete the originals. When given a type and a message, it will set or append that message to the given type. 'isOverride' used to indicate that the message provided should replace any existing value instead of being appended to it (defaults to false).

So store the flash in your handler:

```
request.yar.flash('error', err['message']);
```

and retrieve all the 'error' flashes somewhere else:

```
const allErrorMessages = request.yar.flash('error');
```